# getting duration from two latlng values wihout use addresses in xamarin android

Tags: google-maps-api-3, xamarin.android

I am using google map in xamarin android project.

I want the duration timing between two latlng values without using the addresses of those two points.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the google api to pass the lat and lng for both start point and destination, this will give you the addresses as well as a distance and duration object.

Using the API with the following example:
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592key=YOUR_API_KEY

you get something like:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "67-89 Pacific St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "566 Vermont St, Brooklyn, NY 11207, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.5 mi",
                  "value" : 10422
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "34 mins",
                  "value" : 2037
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```